# The Randoop open source project for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, msdn, randoop

I am working on automatic unit test generation tool for .NET Applications and I found Randoop toolof microsoft research very interesting .I searched for developer forums for randoop and I didn't find many useful results. I found the open source code for randoop which is compiled back in 2010. I actually want to modify the existing code to suit my purpose. Does there exist any seperate developers forum for Randoop development for peer discussion ? or else please suggest any platform for such a discussion.

Comment: Why not contacting one of the members/contributor directly? https://code.google.com/p/randoop/ They might be able to help you.

Comment: @Spock, you gave a pointer to Randoop for Java.  Randoop for .NET is a reimplementation, and the developer groups are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any ongoing development of Randoop.NET.  Microsoft Research did open-source the project, but that seems to be the extent of it.  You can see their discussions webpage at http://randoop.codeplex.com/discussions (it has two conversations, both from 2011).

The "feedback-directed test generation" approach that is implemented by Randoop.NET was pioneered for Java, and the Randoop for Java tool is still maintained.  You can find it at https://code.google.com/p/randoop/.

**Update**:  As of June 2015, ABB Corporation has released an updated version of Randoop.NET at https://github.com/abb-iss/Randoop.NET.  Compared to the original version from Microsoft Research:

- it fixes some bugs
- it adds new features, notably regression assertions for more effective regression testing, method transformers to delete or replace calls to specific methods in the assembly, and richer debug information collection.
- it creates a GUI (as a VS2010 add-in)